# Kafka streaming api to Azure cloud

Tags: java, azure, apache-kafka

Our service provider managing our IoT devices sent us java code to retrieve the data transmitted by these devices.
I would like to send this data easily to my Azure cloud and then be able to make queries on it and do powerBI and reports.

The code look like this :

```
package org.trackunit.tm2;

import com.trackunit.machine_insights.EquipmentExternal;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaClient {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));

        KafkaConsumer<String, EquipmentExternal> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);

        String inputTopic = properties.getProperty("inputTopic");
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(inputTopic));

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, EquipmentExternal> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
            System.out.println(String.format("Received %s records from kafka", records.count()));

            for (ConsumerRecord<String, EquipmentExternal> record : records) {
                EquipmentExternal equipmentDataRecord = record.value();
                System.out.println(equipmentDataRecord.toString());
            }

            consumer.commitAsync();
        }
    }

}
```

With this code I saw all messages in my console. So I guess I have to connect to database or Azure EventHub and push there ?. I try many things but nothing works or I don't understand what I read... any idea or tutorial to get this data in database.

Thanks a lot ;)